# Android - Custom style on Action Bar

Tags: android

is it possible to customize the background (and title) of my action bar in a specific activity? What I have done and it's not working:

```
<style name="AppTheme.BenchTheme"> <!-- style of my activity -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BenchActionBar</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="BenchActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorBench</item>
</style>
```

I want to do it in my style.xml. Is it possible? I know I can do it via code (using something like getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(myColor);)...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First make your Theme extend from Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme.BenchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then in your layout you can already add the toolbar as you want for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/kelly_green"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/MyToolbarElevation"
        >

     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
              android:id="@+id/txt_toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_2sdp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
              />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: That's a solution and it works. Thx. Can you explain me why my solution isn't working? Is the tag  <item name="android:actionBarStyle"> broken?